# How to return multiple tables as one XML?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have the following script:

```
DECLARE @columns TABLE (
    Caption varchar(50),
    Width int);

INSERT INTO @columns 
VALUES ('Id', 0), ('Name', 100);

DECLARE @rows TABLE (
    Id int,
    [Name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @rows 
VALUES (1, 'John'), (2, 'Steve');

SELECT *,
    (SELECT *
     FROM @rows
     FOR XML PATH('Row'), ROOT('Rows'), TYPE, ELEMENTS)
FROM @columns
FOR XML PATH('Column'), ROOT('Results'), TYPE, ELEMENTS;
```

And I need to return the following XML:

```
<Results>
    <Columns>
        <Column>
            <Caption>Id</Caption>
            <Width>0</Width>
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Caption>Name</Caption>
            <Width>100</Width>
        </Column>
    </Columns>
    <Rows>
        <Row>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Name>John</Name>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <Name>Steve</Name>
        </Row>
    </Rows>
</Results>
```

The idea is that I will convert the XML into a `DataSet` with 2 `DataTables` (one for Columns and the other for Rows). I will use this to populate a `DataGridView`.

However, my problem is that the XML I'm generating currently is malformed and isn't the same as I'm expecting.

What is the correct syntax to generate the XML as expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This gets you the result you want, **based** on the data we have:

```
SELECT (SELECT Caption,
               Width
        FROM @columns
        FOR XML PATH('Column'),TYPE) AS [Columns],
       (SELECT Id,
               [Name]
        FROM @rows
        FOR XML PATH('Row'),TYPE) AS [Rows]
FOR XML PATH ('Results');
```

Answer (score 2):

This query generates exactly the result you're expected:

```
SELECT (SELECT clm.Caption,
               clm.Width
        FROM @columns clm
        FOR XML PATH('Column'), TYPE) AS Columns,
       (SELECT rs.Id,
               rs.[Name]
        FROM @rows rs
        FOR XML PATH('Row'),TYPE) AS [Rows]
FOR XML PATH ('Results');
```